# LoadListingInformationAsync throws a FileNotFound exception

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a customer who is unable to do in-app purchasing from one of my Windows 8.1 Store apps.

Looking at the logs, I see that the call to load listing information:

```
await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
```

throws a FileNotFound exception

```
The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'
```

Any idea why this exception is being thrown?

We have less than 100 in-app purchasing items.

Comment: This is just a hunch, but did the customer by any chance upgrade the device from Windows 7? If that's the case, ask the customer to install the latest version of the .Net framework.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reproduce this on your device? I would suggest to run it on the UI thread: `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync());`

Comment: No, I can't repro it. It's happening in production to one user, otherwise works OK.

Comment: It's hard to find the issue when you can't reproduce the bug on your machine. I can only suggest to log some information in that area and publish an update, maybe you can get more info. Or maybe you can ask the customer some info about what he's doing, in what order, what device he's using, etc.
I know it sounds weird, but I actually had an issue where the navigation threw exceptions on Lumia 930 devices, and I had to make the call on the UI thread to fix it, so maybe your problem is related to a device.